# CSS cut half top right border and half right top border

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

How do I achieve this kind of checkbox (Image Shown Below) ? I tried some code, but it won't work as I expected. I am not familiar with css before, after pseudo elements.

[image]

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th9qpdvh/)**

```
.chkbox {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
  -ms-transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
  -moz-transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.chkbox:before {
  right: -1px;
  width: 1px;
  top: -1px;
  height: 8px
}
.chkbox:after {
  top: -1px;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden those corner borders using this below class.

Few other answers are good. But, it doesn't work on some browsers. Another answer affect my **TICK** css class. Finally I found this below solution to solve this issue without compatibility problems.

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/th9qpdvh/4/)

```
.hideWhite{
width:10px;
height:10px;
background:#fff;
border-radius:50%;
position:absolute;
top:-2px;
right:-4px;
display:inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use clip-path? Remove pseudo-elements and just add something like `clip-path: polygon(0 0, 65% 0%, 65% 25%, 100% 25%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);`

```css
.chkbox {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
  -ms-transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
  -moz-transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 65% 0%, 65% 25%, 100% 25%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="chkbox"></div>
```

That's very handy, by the way http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

```css
.chkbox {
  display: none;
}

.chkbox+label {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666666;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 7px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.chkbox+label:before {
  content: "";
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.chkbox+label:after {
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbox">
<label for="check1">Morning</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to override borders like this

```
.chkbox:before {
   content: "";
   width: 7px;
   height: 7px;
   background:white;
   position:absolute;
   right:-1px;
   top:-1px;
}
```

here is fiddle example for you 
https://jsfiddle.net/th9qpdvh/2/

You can also use image for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.chkbox {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    position: relative;
    transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
    -ms-transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
    -moz-transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease 0.125s;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 2px #ccc;
}
.chkbox:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    right: -3px;
    width: 9px;
    top: -3px;
    height: 9px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="chkbox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the input type="checkbox" element into the desired shape directly, because:

1. Input elements don't have pseudo elements.
2. You cannot use clip-path as mentioned in one of the answers because of very low browser support (if that is a concern for you.) [CanIUse Reference](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

So I would suggest you to go with [@Pugazh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42689959/2302156)

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #404040;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin: 7px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before, input[type="checkbox"] + label:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    left: 0;
    top: -1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:after {
    height: 7px;
    width: 7px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    left: 13px;
    top: -1px;
}
```